# Grafana Alert deletion using file provisioning

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-templating, grafana-api

Have anyone worked on alert rules using file provisioning ? like I am looking to delete an entire folder instead of deleting each alert one by one using its UID . the template I use to delete rule is  as below. Since I have some 100 rules, I am looking to delete the entire alert folder . is there any template to do so in file provisioning or any other method ?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 =================================

```
# config file version
apiVersion: 1
# List of alert rule UIDs that should be deleted
deleteRules:
  # <int> organization ID, default = 1
  - orgId: 1
    # <string, required> unique identifier for the rule
    uid: my_id_1
```